# How to conditionally show a button inside ng-repeat in Angular/Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I have an ng-repeat outputting an array:

```
<div ng-repeat="usr in myPage.data.people track by $index">
  <button ng-click="leaveReviewUsr($index)" ng-show="isReviewable(usr)">
      review
  </button>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to conditionally show the button, based on if there is already a record in another collection. Looking at some documentation it looks like I should have a helper to decide to show the button, so I tried

```
isReviewable(usr) {
  console.log(usr);
  if(this.data) {
    console.log(this.data.driverId + " / " + Meteor.userId());
    if(this.data.driverId == Meteor.userId()) {
      console.log(usr);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

in my `this.helpers({`. However this just outputs `undefined` once. I was under the impression that the helper is reactive, so why is it only running once?

Answer (score 1):

`this.helpers({})` is for reactive datasources only and must return a `mongoCursor` via `Collection.find()` or `Collection.findOne()` (or even `Meteor.user()` ). [See docs](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/helpers).

Primitives and functions must be declared in the normal scope, but I propose instead defining the current user in a helper:

```
this.helpers({
    currentUser() { return Meteor.user(); }
});
```

and then using `ng-show="usr.data.driverId === currentUser._id"`in your button.